# Laptop resumes from suspend while lid is closed

Tags: suspend, suspend-resume, power-management, acpi, overheating

I have a Dell Studio 15 and I am running Ubuntu 10.10.

When I close my lid or select the suspend option, the machine suspends as indicated by the slowly pulsing power indicator.

I'll put the machine in my bag and after a while it seems that the machine resumes, at least I think. When ever I go to get it, it's overheated and the system cannot resume. I am guessing that the processor resets in this overheat condition, but heat is still generated. This has happened about three times and I'm getting worried that I'll end up damaging the machine.

How can I diagnose why the system is resuming from suspend? Can I force it to never resume from suspend if the lid is down?

Comment: I may be getting something similar with two other laptops (Dell Inspiron 17 and Dell Studio 17), but I don't know how to duplicate this behaviour.  Even a bug report on launchpad would be helpful.

Comment: Not a decent answer, I know, but I've taken to shutting down, rather than suspending, my laptop, for precisely this reason. Ubuntu starts / shuts so quickly, I find it's pretty much the same experience as suspending / resuming Windows.

Comment: I do marvel at how quickly it starts up /shuts down. My main problem is saving state resuming state. I have not gotten hibernate to work. The option doesn't even always appear in the menu for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

[Removing the lid's ability to resume from a suspended state](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=293883) might be helpful as a temporary hack (though is admittedly, not a solution).